# USB to serial driver for Mac OSX (10.14.6) Mojave

Tags: macos-mojave

**I am using USB to TTL serial cable in my mac.** I have followed the instructions in the links [Adafruit-driver-mac](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/software-installation-mac) and [mac-os-driver-installations](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=229&pcid=41),and installed the driver successfully. However after restarting my computer **the serial cable is  still not detected. I checked ls /dev/tty.usb.** But no such device is shown in the list (except my BBB).

So, is it that the drivers not updated for MacOS 10.14 (Mojave) or there is anything else I am missing.

The USB to TTL serial cable I am using **is PL2303 HX.**

Answer (score -2):

For driver install follow this link. [link](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm)